# Chrome on W10 cannot remember my default magnet handler

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bittorrent, magnet

1. In `chrome://settings/handlers`, for magnet links, I can see my BitTorrent client's URL.
2. However the `default` is always missing, so I click on the 3 dot menu and `Set as default`
3. A `Default` will be added below my URL, but also opens up the Windows settings `Choose default apps by protocol`
4. I have gone through the very long list several times and can never find the magnet entry. Unfortunately, there is also no search button nor manual `Add` button
5. Thus, my attempts always ends up failing at this step
6. Once I restart my Chrome, the URL no longer has `Default`
7. How can I make Chrome remember and use my client's URL whenever I click on a magnet link in Chrome?